# Woocommerce login through phone number

Tags: authentication, woocommerce

I am building a website using Woocommerce.By default the username is the user's email address.I want to provide the users the feature to login through their phone number also. How can i do that? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting one. There are a couple of things to consider:

1. Has the user actually entered their phone number against their account already, or given their number when they've made a purchase?
2. Are we using the billing phone number for their login?

Assuming both of those things are true, you can hook into the `authenticate` filter, search for users with matching `billing_phone` meta, and return that user's *actual* username:

```
<?php

///
//  Allow login via phone number
///

function vnmAdmin_emailLogin($user, $username, $password) {

    //  Try logging in via their billing phone number

    if (is_numeric($username)) {

        //  The passed username is numeric - that's a start

        //  Now let's grab all matching users with the same phone number:

        $matchingUsers = get_users(array(
            'meta_key'     => 'billing_phone',
            'meta_value'   => $username,
            'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
        ));

        //  Let's save time and assume there's only one. 

        if (is_array($matchingUsers)) {
            $username = $matchingUsers[0]->user_login;
        }

    }

    return wp_authenticate_username_password(null, $username, $password);
}

add_filter('authenticate', 'vnmAdmin_loginWithPhoneNumber', 20, 3);

?>
```

**NOTE:** This method isn't absolutely robust; for example it doesn't check for whitespace (either in the 'login' number or the retrieved user meta number); and it simply makes the assumption that the first user it finds is the correct one - not ideal if, for whatever reason, you have more than one user using the same phone number. But having said that, I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Hey,

The billing phone number is a mandatory field for the user to sign up.
I want that the user must be able to register either through their email or phone and either of them can be his username.
 I'll try your code in the meanwhile and get back to you. Thank You! :-)

Comment: @vkm With this technique, their username will still be their username (e.g. `indextwo`) assuming it's a standard user registration form, but they will be able to sign in with either their username *or* their phone number. This should work for that.

Answer (score 0):

Function name was not same as given in add_filter callback in @indextwo answer. I wanted to authenticate using email and phone number. Used @indextwo answer and came up with this.

```
///
//  Allow login via phone number and email
///

function vnmAdmin_loginWithPhoneNumber($user, $username, $password) {

    //  Try logging in via their billing phone number

    if (is_numeric($username)) {

        //  The passed username is numeric - that's a start

        //  Now let's grab all matching users with the same phone number:

        $matchingUsers = get_users(array(
            'meta_key'     => 'billing_phone',
            'meta_value'   => $username,
            'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
        ));

        //  Let's save time and assume there's only one. 

        if (is_array($matchingUsers) && !empty($matchingUsers)) {
            $username = $matchingUsers[0]->user_login;
        }

    }elseif (is_email($username)) {

        //  The passed username is email- that's a start

        //  Now let's grab all matching users with the same email:

        $matchingUsers = get_user_by_email($username);
        //  Let's save time and assume there's only one. 

        if (isset($matchingUsers->user_login)) {
            $username = $matchingUsers->user_login;

        }

    }

    return wp_authenticate_username_password(null, $username, $password);
}

add_filter('authenticate', 'vnmAdmin_loginWithPhoneNumber', 20, 3);
```